# How do I remove windows reserved character in PHP?

Tags: php

I'd like to remove any windows reserved character from my string. I have to remove these chars :

```
\,/,:,*,?,",<,>,|, and spaces
```

How do I remove those chars?

Example:

```
$string = "21/002-4/ASG* -47";
```

Result:

```
"21002-4ASG-47"
```

Comment: `str_replace()` is one way to go. What are you trying to achieve here? There might be better alternatives.

Comment: For a filename?

Comment: I don't know PHP, but it seems similar to Perl. In Perl this could lead you on the right way: `$x="23*23;jh:k>m";  $y=($x =~ y/\\\/:*?"<>//dr)`. `$y` will have removed all characters from `$x` that are listed.

Comment: I have a text that contain those char. I'd like to remove them.

Comment: We will be more able to point you in the right direction if you explain a bit what you're using this for. There are many ways to Rome, but they're all different.

Comment: I'd like to use preg_replace. See edit

Comment: Both `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()` are possible solutions.

Comment: now u have 2 answers, did u checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "21/002-4/ASG* -47";
$new = preg_replace('/[\\/\:\*\?\"<>\|\s]+/', '', $string);
echo $new;
```

will do the trick, here's live example:

https://3v4l.org/b8IiE

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rmB

Comment: it has error. Message: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ':'

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the result with `'/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/'` pattern by using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string='21/002-4/ASG* -47';
echo preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

**Result:**

```
21002-4ASG-47
```

As per your comment, if you want to remove only specific characters (Defined), then [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is an another solution. One more thing [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is quick then to [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Example with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$string='21/002-4/ASG* -47'; // your string
$char = array('/','*',' '); // defined all characters which need to be removed
echo str_replace($char, "", $string); // result should be 21002-4ASG-47
```

Comment: is this remove all special char? I only want to remove the reserved char from windows and spaces

Comment: according to your expected result, it will remove all special character @ashura91

Comment: yes. it become my expected result. But, I do not want to remove all special char, only specific char

Comment: for specific, you can use str_replace. @ashura91

Comment: @ashura91: check example with str_replace updated in answer